# Short assignment statement with validation

Tags: c#, .net

There is a cycle.

Me need to check the value every time, and only once assign True, and then check in a circle but do not re-set the value again True! And the code must be one line! And as short as possible!

The code in case #2 is suitable, it is executed only 1 time, but it is long and ugly. The code in case #1 is already more interesting, but it is necessary to make the assignment every time, even if it is not required ...

```
private bool RemoveX509Certificate(StoreName storName, StoreLocation storLocation, String hash)
{
    bool resultExecution = false;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hash))
        return resultExecution;

    X509Store store = new X509Store(storName, storLocation);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;
    foreach (X509Certificate2 elemCert in store.Certificates)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(elemCert.Thumbprint))
            continue;
        if (String.Equals(hash, elemCert.Thumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            store.Remove(elemCert);

            /*
            resultExecution = (resultExecution != true) ? true : true; // #1

            if (resultExecution != true) // #2
                resultExecution = true;
            */
        }
    }
    return resultExecution;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Comment: I don't understand your code, it doesn''t make sense. You are never assigning `false` to `resultExecution` without returning immediately from the method, so in the loop it's always `true`. Why you need that strange check at all?

Comment: Both of your cases are effectively `resultExecution = true;`, but why are you setting it all since it's never used?

Comment: please read the text again. I want to make a nice assignment. Maybe I don't know the clever and tricks or subtleties of the language. resultExecution - this is the flag of the function, if there was a certificate, it means that the function is true

Comment: The  best you can get is option 2. But maybe you can break the loop or return true from the method in case that condition matches. Then you dont need to think aboout this, it would also be more efficient.

Comment: It's still unclear to me why you don't write `resultExecution = true;`. Just assign it every time. What downside would that have? (This is a local variable... the assignment is going to be *massively* faster than any of the rest of the code in the method.)

Comment: Or better - remove the local variable entirely, and just `return true;` where you would set it, and `return false;` at the end of the method.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm worried about the CLR, which unnecessarily needs to assign the same value to a memory location on the stack (or heap), because there could be a class instead of a Boolean ...

Comment: @KUL: What do you mean by "because there could be a class instead of a Boolean"? It sounds like you're pico-optimizing here, without any evidence of it being a problem... whereas actually returning from the method as soon as you find the first match would be a *much* more significant optimization. (Probably still irrelevant in most cases, but it could potentially save a lot of comparisons.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I probably made a mistake, assuming that there can be several certificates with the same hash in the storage - a variable was used for this. Regarding comparison and assignment - if you do not look at a specific code, but think in general , then-the comparison operation is cheaper and easier than the assignment operation?!

Comment: @KUL: Ah, I'd missed that you want to call store.Remove. So you can't actually exit early. But in general, no I would *not* assume that performing a comparison and conditionally assigning is cheaper than unconditional assignment for a local variable. And I would certainly only make code more complicated than it needs to be after *testing* that the hypothetical optimization actually has an impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you question as about alternatives to

```
/*
resultExecution = (resultExecution != true) ? true : true; // #1

if (resultExecution != true) // #2
    resultExecution = true;
*/
```

### 1 line and super short

```
resultExecution = true; #3
```

### 1 line and assign once

```
if (resultExecution != true)  resultExecution = true; #4
```

and if `resultExecution` is not nullable:

```
if (!resultExecution) resultExecution = true; #5
```

### 1 line, super short, assignment only once

```
public static void f(ref bool b) { if (!b) b = true; }

...

f(ref resultExecution); #6
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your store will only ever contain one matching element. You can avoid the loop altogether. A simplified version of your method:

```
private bool RemoveX509Certificate(StoreName storName, StoreLocation storLocation, String hash)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hash))
        return false;

    X509Store store = new X509Store(storName, storLocation);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

    // SingleOrDefault will get the only matching item or null if none or more than one exist in the collection.
    // You could use FirstOrDefault but that will match only one even if there are more than one.
    X509Certificate2 elemCert = store.Certificates
        .SingleOrDefault(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Thumbprint) 
                          && string.Equals(hash, c.Thumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    if (elemCert == null)
        return false;

    store.Remove(elemCert);
    return true;
}
```

Alternatively if you expect the store to contain multiple certificates with the same hash, which I expect is unlikely, you can get a filtered list of certificates to loop instead which also removes the need to check and reassign the return value:

```
private bool RemoveX509Certificate(StoreName storName, StoreLocation storLocation, String hash)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(hash))
        return false;

    X509Store store = new X509Store(storName, storLocation);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

    // using Where here gets an array of all matching items.
    X509Certificate2[] certificates = store.Certificates
        .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Thumbprint) 
                 && string.Equals(hash, c.Thumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        .ToArray();

    if (certificates.Length == 0)
        return false;

    foreach (X509Certificate2 elemCert in certificates)
        store.Remove(elemCert);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Yes, there can be duplicate hashes in the storage. No, the algorithm does not need to be improved. I think LINQ is a bit redundant here ...

Comment: So the second suggestion should be what you need. As well as satisfying the condition to only 'set' the response to true once, this also avoids modifying the collection while enumerating it which can cause problems in many cases.

Comment: "if you expect the store to contain multiple certificates with the same hash, which I expect is unlikely" - that is, the store can only have 1 certificate with 1 unique hash?! I think I missed this moment ... thank you for the thought!

Answer (score 0):

my soul calmed down

```
...
if (String.Equals(hash, elemCert.Thumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    store.Remove(elemCert);
    if (!resultExecution) resultExecution = true;
}
...
```